# How to send object via ajax after fully updated the object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this js code inside an event:

```
var userData = tableWidget.grid('userData');
console.log(tableWidget.grid('userData'));
$.ajax({
    "url": "../../server/query.aspx?tableEvent=reordercolumns&table=SubContractor",
    "data": { dataColumnOrder: JSON.stringify(userData) },
    "dataType": "json",
    "type": "GET",
    "error": function () {
        console.log("Something wrong with the columns' reorder saving process");
    }
});
```

Let's say userData has two conditions. Before and after the event is fired:

`userData before event`: `[a, b, c]`

`userData after event`: `[a, c, b]`

In my case, when the event is fired, the `console.log(tableWidget.grid('userData'));` contains the `userData after event` as it should be. But, when I send it via ajax, in the server, the object contains `userData before event` instead. I assume ajax sends the object before the object is fully updated.

My question, is there any way to execute the `ajax` after `var userData = tableWidget.grid('userData');` is fully updated?

**Updated**: it turns out that the problem seems occurred from `stringify` function. Here is the screenshot of my object with and without `stringify`:

Without Stringify `console.log(userData);`:

[image]

With Stringify `console.log(JSON.stringify(userData));`:

```
{
    "view": "SubContractorGridView",
    "title": "SubContractor Grid View",
    "settings": {
        "colOrder": ["Id", "ExtKey", "InsertionDate", "DeletionDate", "Name", "Address", "ZipCode", "EmailAddress", "PhoneNumber", "UserName", "Password", "LastUpdate", "Price"],
        "orderBy": "Name",
        "orderDir": "asc"
    },
    "columns": [{
            "dbField": "Id",
            "show": true,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 89,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 90,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 90
        }, {
            "dbField": "ExtKey",
            "show": false,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 120,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 150,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 100
        }, {
            "dbField": "InsertionDate",
            "show": true,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 100,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 100,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 110
        }, {
            "dbField": "DeletionDate",
            "show": false,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 90,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 90,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 100
        }, {
            "dbField": "Name",
            "show": true,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 130,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 90,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 90
        }, {
            "dbField": "Address",
            "show": true,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 90,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 90,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 90
        }, {
            "dbField": "ZipCode",
            "show": true,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 90,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 90,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 90
        }, {
            "dbField": "EmailAddress",
            "show": true,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 90,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 90,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 90
        }, {
            "dbField": "PhoneNumber",
            "show": true,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 90,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 90,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 90
        }, {
            "dbField": "UserName",
            "show": true,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 90,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 90,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 90
        }, {
            "dbField": "Password",
            "show": true,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 90,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 90,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 90
        }, {
            "dbField": "LastUpdate",
            "show": true,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 90,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 90,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 90
        }, {
            "dbField": "Price",
            "show": true,
            "widthMobile": 90,
            "widthPhablet": 90,
            "widthMiniTablet": 90,
            "widthTablet": 90,
            "widthSmallDesktop": 90,
            "widthDesktop": 90,
            "widthLargeDesktop": 90
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see the column's order is somehow not changed with stringify.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yup that's right. is it possible if the ajax sends the object before it's updated? I mean, it executes the ajax first prior to `var userData = tableWidget.grid('userData');` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to try like this......

```
  var userData = tableWidget.grid('userData');
console.log(tableWidget.grid('userData'));
$.ajax({
    url: "../../server/query.aspx?tableEvent=reordercolumns&table=SubContractor",
    data: { 'dataColumnOrder': userData},
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    success:function(response){
      //write JS when ajax call success
      console.log('success');
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("Something wrong with the columns' reorder saving process");
    }
});
```

Comment: There is no error either. For the ajax it works fine, only for the object, it is not updated in the server, even though the object is already updated on the front-end.

Comment: are you getting data using `console.log(userData)`?

Comment: No, I use `var userData = tableWidget.grid('userData');` to get the object.

Comment: are you also get object's variables in `query.aspx`?

Comment: Yes I get it. But it contains the non-updated one. So, it seems like the ajax sends the object before it's loaded or even before the event is triggered.

Comment: way of ajax is correct but i have not any idea on `asp.net` so...dont know how you got like this...

Comment: I missed something from your code. the `JSON.stringify()`. I think this is the source of the problem. Because when I tried `console.log(JSON.stringify(userData));`. It results the non-updated one. Do you know it could be like that?

Comment: yes you have to use `JSON.stringify(userData)` if the response from server is in `json`format.

Comment: and use `JSON.parse()` to parsing json to array.

Comment: Ok, now I know the real source of the problem. When I print it directly like `console.log(userData);`. The order of the data is update, which is correct. But when I print it like `console.log(JSON.stringify(userData));`. It doesn't update the array. Do you have any clue about this?

Comment: can i see your data `console.log(userData)`?it must be in format like `var1=val1&var2=val2` like this..

Comment: Sure, I attached the screenshot of it to my post.